# process.start not running exe when application hosted as windows service

Tags: service, windows-services, console-application, exe, .net-7.0

I am running my app as a console application there it is working fine the .exe runs on `Process.Start` The issue is When I hosted my .Net app as windows service instead of console app, then it is not running .exe. I have also given my user access to service by adding my credentials in logon tab in service properties.

```
ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo();
            process.FileName = @"C:\ack\Ack_Installer\Ack_Installer\Acc11.exe";
            process.Arguments = arguments;
            process.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
            process.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            var pro = Process.Start(process);
```

I tried to run service with my user by changing logon credentials in service properties logon tab.

Comment: What's the error message returned from "Process.Start(process)"?